# What's the format of the intermediate instruction in CPython?

Tags: python, cpython

For example, `0 STORE_NAME 0 (sys)` is part of the instruction for `import sys`. Is there any documentation for this instruction format? What's more, is this format a standard of Python? Or implementation specific?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is [Python bytecode](http://docs.python.org/library/dis.html). It is specific to CPython, and even to specific versions.